# How to check in TSQL if grouped column contains value and depends of result create colum with value true or false

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have 3 tables. Check screenshots.

[image]
[image]

I would like to have view with 3 column
Is, Title, IsVotedByUser

In column IsVotedByUser I need to use any "aggregate" function which will check if in table UserInquiry is row with declared variable @UserId.
Depends of result I would like to have True or False in this column.

Something like this:
[image]

I tried also:
[image]

Thanks

Comment: For the count function is does not matter what count 1 or 0, replace 0 to null or remove else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Conditional Aggregate`

```
SELECT i.id,
       i.title,
       Count(CASE WHEN ui.userid = @userid THEN 1 END)
FROM   Inquiry I
       LEFT JOIN UserInquiry ui
              ON ui.userid = i.id
GROUP  BY i.id,i.title
```

Comment: But if I use count() function I have bad result - check screenshot on bottom of my post

Comment: @tonco - Remove the Else part in case that is the mistake. Updated check now

Comment: Or use SUM instead of COUNT.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT i.Id, i.Title,
    CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN ui.UserId = @UserId then 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
    THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END as IsVotedByUser
FROM [dbo].[Inquery] as i
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[UserInquery] as ui
ON i.Id = ui.InquiryId
GROUP BY i.Id, i.Title
```